# TypeScript circular type alias produces no error and instead widens unit types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-alias, typescript-generics, conditional-types

It is hard to explain what I mean. I have an `Eval` type that is oversimplified to let us focus on error. Its initial goal was to evaluate type operator and parameter tree into a boolean `true` or `false`, but I can't resolve an issue where there is no error report for `circular type alias`, but things don't work as intended. 
[Here is the link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20UnionIncludes%3CTUnion%2C%20TValue%3E%20%3D%20Extract%3CTUnion%2C%20TValue%3E%20extends%20never%20%3F%20false%20%3A%20true%3B%0D%0Atype%20Or%3CT%20extends%20boolean%5B%5D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20UnionIncludes%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20true%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Condition%20%3D%20boolean%20%7C%20OperatorOr%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20OperatorOr%3CTConds%20extends%20Condition%5B%5D%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%20'__OR__'%3A%20TConds%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Eval%3CTCond%20extends%20Condition%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TCond%20extends%20boolean%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20TCond%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TCond%20extends%20OperatorOr%3Cinfer%20TOrParams%3E%20%3F%20Or%3CEvalAll%3CTOrParams%3E%3E%20%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20EvalAll%20%3CTConds%20extends%20Condition%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bi%20in%20keyof%20TConds%5D%3A%20TConds%5Bi%5D%20extends%20Condition%20%3F%20Eval%3CTConds%5Bi%5D%3E%20%3A%20TConds%5Bi%5D%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20EvalAll2%3CTConds%20extends%20Condition%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bi%20in%20keyof%20TConds%5D%3A%20TConds%5Bi%5D%20extends%20Condition%20%3F%20Eval%3CTConds%5Bi%5D%3E%20%3A%20TConds%5Bi%5D%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20expected%20%3D%20EvalAll2%3C%5B%20OperatorOr%3C%5B%20true%2C%20true%20%5D%3E%20%5D%3E%20%2F%2F%20%5Btrue%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20actual%20%20%20%3D%20EvalAll%20%3C%5B%20OperatorOr%3C%5B%20true%2C%20true%20%5D%3E%20%5D%3E%20%2F%2F%20%5Bboolean%5D%3B). I expect `EvalAll` to evaluate to `[true]`, but it is `[boolean]`. Why is this so and what can I do to resolve this without having to leverage code generation and create tons of duplicates of `EvalAll` and `Eval`?

Code from playground:

```
type UnionIncludes<TUnion, TValue> = Extract<TUnion, TValue> extends never ? false : true;
type Or<T extends boolean[]>       = UnionIncludes<T[number], true>;

type Condition = boolean | OperatorOr;

interface OperatorOr<TConds extends Condition[] = any> { '__OR__': TConds; }

type Eval<TCond extends Condition> = (
    TCond extends boolean                     ? TCond                   :
    TCond extends OperatorOr<infer TOrParams> ? Or<EvalAll<TOrParams>>  :
    never
);

type EvalAll <TConds extends Condition[]> = { [i in keyof TConds]: TConds[i] extends Condition ? Eval<TConds[i]> : TConds[i]; };
type EvalAll2<TConds extends Condition[]> = { [i in keyof TConds]: TConds[i] extends Condition ? Eval<TConds[i]> : TConds[i]; };

type expected = EvalAll2<[ OperatorOr<[ true, true ]> ]> // [true];
type actual   = EvalAll <[ OperatorOr<[ true, true ]> ]> // [boolean];
```

Comment: looks like a bug in TypeScript 3.3; both expected and actual types are [true] in [3.2 playground](https://typescript-play.js.org) and 3.4  installed with `npm i typescript@next`

Comment: @artem Hmm, you are right, thanks